# Mapping a JPA bi-directional @OneToOne with primary/foreign key mapping on non-owning side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

> ***Post-Post-Edit** now appended to end of post.
>
> Whilst writing this question i came across some documentation that produced a different error when it was applied. I still felt the following information was still relevant to onlookers. For edit see **Pre-Post Edit** below.

I want to implement the following bi-directional relationship in **JPA 2.1**:

[image: mapping diagram]

My current attempt looks like this:

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    private long aId;
    private AMore aMore;
    private String foo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(/*...*/)
    public long getAId() { return aId; }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // this is owning side
    public AMore getAMore() { return aMore; }

    public void setAMore(AMore aMore) {
        this.aMore = aMore;
        this.aMore.setA(this);
    }

    // set aId
    // set/get foo;
}


public class AMore implements Serializable {

    private A a;
    private long version = 1L;
    private String bar;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "aMore") // this is non-owning-side
    @JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id")
    public A getA() { return a; }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "A_MORE_VER")
    public long getVersion() {
        return version; // not sure if relevant but thought i'd add this incase.
    }

    // set A, version
    // set/get bar

}
```

Attempting to create the EntityManagerFactory fails with this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:599)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1786)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1730)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1617)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Digging into the code, I can see that the inner call to `bindFK` expects the `referencedIdentity` (`AMore`) to contain an identifier (obtained through `referencedIdentity.getIdentifier()` which returns null, causing the error:

```
// TableBinder.java ...
else {
    idColumns = referencedEntity.getIdentifier().getColumnIterator();
}
// ...
```

---

### Pre-Post-Edit

So I have edited the code after some reading and produced a different error so I thought: Instead of creating a new question, the above information would hopefully still be relevant to answer seekers.

After reading the [documentation on one to one with primary and foreign key relationship](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_OneToOne_id_annotation) more carefully, I changed my aMore class to be like so:

```
public class AMore implements Serializable {

    private long aId;
    private A a;
    private long version = 1L;
    private String bar;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    private long getAId() { return aId; }

    // removed Id from here and placed on above long property.
    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "aMore") // this is non-owning-side
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id") //CHANGED FROM JoinColumn -> PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public A getA() { return a; }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "A_MORE_VER")
    public long getVersion() {
        return version; // not sure if relevant but thought i'd add this incase.
    }

    // set A
    // set/get bar, version

}
```

Now my hibernate query that fetches the A by its foo field contains an incorrect column name in the query:

```
select           a0_.a_id as a_id1_1_
                 a0_.a_more_a_id as a_f2_1_, -- as well as being a non-existing field, this should not even be included in the query to fetch only the A Entity info. (the relationship is a `FetchType.LAZY`)
                 a0_.foo as foo3_1_
from             MYSCHEMA.A as a0_
where            a0_.foo = ? -- bound at runtime, e.g. 'spam'
```

I have a feeling this is due to the way the aMore is mapped on the A side.

Any pointers?

---

### Post-Post-Edit

After applying both @JBNizet and @XtremeBaumer's suggestions, And also changing the id from a primitive to wrapper type [`Long`] I am encountering an Id generation problem.

If I create instances of both entities for persisting at the same time, The `aId` on `AMore` is not populated how I expect and gives the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.example.AMore
```

I assume that because the id for both `A` and `AMore` is null and needs to be assigned to the generated Id for `A`, then `A` needs persisting, fetching and assigning-of-id to `AMore`.

My new mapping looks like this:

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    private Long aId;
    private AMore aMore;
    private String foo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(/*...*/)
    public Long getAId() { return aId; }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    public CourseOffering getAMore() { return aMore; }

    public void setAMore(AMore aMore) {
        this.aMore = aMore;
        this.aMore.setA(this);
    }

    // set aId
    // set/get foo;
}


    public class AMore implements Serializable {

        private Long aId;
        private A a;
        private long version = 1L;
        private String bar;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "a_id")
        private Long getAId() { return aId; }

        @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @MapsId
        public CourseOffering getA() { return a; }

        // set A, aId
        // set/get bar

    }
```

Comment: You're not understanding what mappedBy is all about. mappedBy says: I'm the inverse side. Look on the other side to know how this association is mapped. So, adding a JoinColumn or PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation on a field annotated with OneToOne(mappedBy = ...) doesn't make sense: you just told JPA, with mappedBy, that the mapping of the association was defined on the other side of the association.

Comment: Make AMore the owning side, and use MapsId.

Answer (score 0):

i found this [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and tried to use it on your classes:

```
public class AMore implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long aId;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private A a;
    private long version = 1L;
    private String bar;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
}


public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long aId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascafeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private AMore aMore;

    private String foo;

    public long getAId() {
        return aId;
    }

    public AMore getAMore() {
        return aMore;
    }

    public void setAMore(AMore aMore) {
        this.aMore = aMore;
        this.aMore.setA(this);
    }

}
```

maybe this works for you

Comment: I have tried this solution, however the problem I have now is that the `"ids for this class [AMore] must be manually assigned before calling save()"` given that the aId is not assigned before persist on the AMore class, it wants me to persist the parent entity and assign the id to the AMore from the generated value then persist the child entity. Something seems fishy about this as i thought that sequence would be managed by the JPA provider.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JBNizet AND @XtremeBaumer for your contributions. A number of things to note in the eventual solution:

1. The `aId` property should be a wrapper class (`Long`) instead of the primitive class (`long`) for both entities in order for the JPA provider to recognize the need to generate an ID using the `@GenerationValue`

   > default value of `0` for `long` is a valid ID so it looks for an entity with `0` Id and errors when persisting multiple new entities in one session.
2. place `@MapsId` annotation above the `@OneToOne` relationship in order to inform JPA Provider that the `@Id` field maps to the relationship entity's `@Id` field.

   > note, this applies automatically to our case as we have a single id field and not a composite id using `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId`. see documentation on [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) for information about how to map a composite key with the primary key of the parent entity.
3. The mappedBy parameter on the `@OneToOne` annotation should exist on the parent's reference side because the child entity "owns" the id reference to its parent.
4. Ensure that the toString and equals/hashcode does not includes the reverse relationship deep copy value in order to avoid an infinite loop scenario.

The final solution was an edit of @XtremeBaumer's solution:

```
public class A implements Serializable {

    private Long aId;
    private AMore aMore;
    private String foo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(/*...*/)
    public Long getAId() { return aId; }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    public CourseOffering getAMore() { return aMore; }

    public void setAMore(AMore aMore) {
        this.aMore = aMore;
        this.aMore.setA(this);
    }

    // set aId
    // set/get foo;
}


    public class AMore implements Serializable {

        private Long aId;
        private A a;
        private long version = 1L;
        private String bar;

        @Id // no need to specify @Column here as @MapsId on getA() informs JPA that this field represents the parent entity.
        private Long getAId() { return aId; }

        @MapsId // resolves issue with "need to manually save id" error
        @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id") // required
        public CourseOffering getA() { return a; }

        // set A, aId
        // set/get bar

    }
```